# Multiple Transmitting Antennas On Different Frequencies In Close Proximity

Tags: antenna-system, filter

I am working on a project where I’m going to have multiple transmitting antennas in very close proximity (in a nosecone of a rocket). There are 3 different radio systems. Our 433 MHz 1 watt telemetry system, a 2.4GHz 4w video system, and a required backup 900mhz GPS system.

All of these antennas are going to be vertical and within a few inches of each other. They will share a large metal bulkhead ground plane.

What kind of things do I need to take into consideration when designing this system. 433 and 2.4 ghz aren’t too much of an issue to my knowledge because they aren’t multiples of each other, but 900 is a pretty close multiple of 433. Could I add a low pass filter to the 433 transmitter and a high pass filter to the 900 MHz transmitter? What kind of hardware would I need? How would I design these filters?

Thanks!